# Why do Lambda expressions in Java 8 implement a functional interface, instead of a delegate as in C#?

Tags: c#, java, lambda, java-8

Many developers who work on projects in Java and on other projects in C# are used to the C# delegate syntax.

Also, the C# delegate syntax is much shorter than the Java functional interface syntax:

Example in C#:

```
public delegate void ProcessBook(Book book);
```

Same example in Java:

```
public interface ProcessBook {
    void processBook(Book book);
}
```

As C# has in the past adopted much of the Java syntax, why did we not adopt this C# delegate syntax in Java 8?

Comment: Where do you declare that `delegate` method in C#?

Comment: C# had delegate before lambdas. Java did not want to introduce the extra concept of delegates instead of the already existing functional interface. In general, both in C# and Java the `=>` (or `->` syntax) is very common. That's the 'sugar', you have ""functional interfaces"" for ever now.

Comment: This a `"guess what the developers might have been thinking"` type of question, one that generates a lot of discussion and little concrete solutions.

Comment: You can use references to methods that do not implement any interface. Just a method signature match. I guess this is what you meant with C# delegates in this context. Next thing, delegates never existed in Java.

Comment: Answer to "Where do you declare that delegate method in C#?": see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288459(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

probably because of backward compatibility. when you use interface, you can use it with all the existing api (and java's strength is the plenty of libraries). for example you can use lambda in every place instead of Runnable, Comparable etc. But when you create some new concept / new keyword, all existing libraries can't benefit from it - they have to be rewritten to work with this new construct